# IF EXISTS (SELECT) in SQL Server not working as expected

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, exists

I have a code like this:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = @id)
BEGIN
    UPDATE table
    SET stock = stock + @stock
    WHERE id = @id
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [table] ([id], [name], [stock])
    VALUES (@id, @name, @stock)
END
```

But, this code isn't working and I am unable to find the root cause for the same. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean when saying "doesn't working'? Is your table's name actually "table"?

Comment: Is ID is Auto_increment column ??

Comment: what exactly error is syntax is correct

Comment: One obvious issue with this code is that it won't (necessarily) act correctly if multiple callers execute the code at the same time. But at the moment it's unclear what actual problem you're seeking help with here.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: provide your Table Structure

Comment: The code doesn't affect a table. I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

Your code and syntax is correct. Let's see a sample example:

```
if EXISTS(select * from dbo.tbName where Id=1)

BEGIN
print 1
END

ELSE
BEGIN
print 2
END
```

Answer (score -1):

`table` is a reserved keyword. so I guess you have a trivial syntax error: `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'table'.` Wrap it with `[]`, as you already did for `INSERT` statement

```
IF EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE id = @id)
BEGIN
        UPDATE  [table] SET     stock   = stock + @stock
        WHERE   id      = @id
END
ELSE
BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [table] ([id]
        ,[name]
        ,[stock])
            VALUES
            (
                @id,@name,@stock
            )
        END
```

Answer (score -1):

I do not see any error in your code, I tried to replicate the process and it is working fine for me. Can you tell me what is the error you are facing exactly.

The following is the code I tried to replicate your scenario:

```
 CREATE TABLE stocks (
    id INT
    ,NAME VARCHAR(100)
    ,stock BIGINT
    )

CREATE PROCEDURE InsertStocks @id INT
    ,@name VARCHAR(100)
    ,@stock BIGINT
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (
            SELECT *
            FROM stocks
            WHERE id = @id
            )
    BEGIN
        UPDATE stocks
        SET stock = stock + @stock
        WHERE id = @id
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO stocks (
            [id]
            ,[name]
            ,[stock]
            )
        VALUES (
            @id
            ,@name
            ,@stock
            )
    END
END

INSERT INTO stocks
VALUES (
    1
    ,'abc'
    ,200
    )

INSERT INTO stocks
VALUES (
    2
    ,'abc'
    ,300
    )

INSERT INTO stocks
VALUES (
    3
    ,'abc'
    ,500
    )

EXEC Insertstocks 1
    ,'abc'
    ,700
```

This is updated successfully in my case.